# Is it possible to use List<T> outside of Main()?

Tags: c#, list, program-entry-point

I am trying to create a simple data entry system in C# (just for self learning) and trying to understand List.
I make a simple console system for data entry, insert students and teachers (which have title, name, surname, dob, coursetaught or courselearned, etc etc). What I also wanted to do was to add every newly created Person (Teacher or Student) with its unique number into an array. Then I discovered Lists. Now here is my problem:

I have a person base class and a teacher, student classes that inherit. In Main I can create a new var stu1, create a list named Studentslist and add stu1, stu2, stuX to that list. I can access the list OK etc.

But I'd like to do this in the Student class. If I do this in the constructor, it will create the Studentslist. But then when I go to use addStu to list method (my own method within the Student class) or add it as soon as the list is created (I have tried a couple of different approaches), I can see the data going into the list but when I call it in main the list will be null and I would get the

> System.NullReferenceException:'Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object'

Here's my code:

```
public Student(string title, string name, string surname, string dob, string degreename = "") : base(title, name, surname, dob)
    {

        if (stucount == 0) // if this is the very first student, create the list Studentslist for the very first time AND and the very first student to the list
        {
            stucount++;
            List<string> Studentslist = new List<string>();
            Studentslist.Add(this.getStuIDtitleNameSurname()); // this part goes OK, however if I try access this from Main, it will throw System.NullReferenceException

        }
        else
        { stucount++;

            string studat = this.getStuIDtitleNameSurname();
            Studentslist.Add(studat); //when I add a another student in Main (I only have one Main, that is in the Program.cs) the code breaks here. 

        }
```

As I said if I do all of this in Main it's all fine and dandy, as I think it working in that instance of the main. Perhaps the way I am doing it is not how this should be done. Can someone wiser enlighten me :) Is there a way I can keep this in memory/database somewhere or do I need to do the work in Main in that instance.

Comment: I doubt your code will compile as it stands, because you're declaring `Studentslist` in the `if` statement, and then trying to access it from the `else`. It won't be able to see it because it's defined within the scope of the `if` statement. Are you sure your code compiles? Alternatively, have you shown us all relevant code?

Comment: If you want to have a list of all the Students you have to put it on a common place, i.e : on the Main. Then create students using you Student class constructor from Main, and then Add student to your list declared on the main.

Comment: It is not a good OOP practice in this case to have a list of students in the student class. It is better to have list of students in the place you want list of students (like main method) or create a class called School and have list of students and list of teachers

Comment: Your question appears as two big "slabs" of text which makes it difficult to read. So far as I can make out, the first slab is just background and not really necessary to the question (you can move it down and make it a footnote *after* the question if you think it's important). Whilst we appreciate knowing something about *what you're trying to accomplish*, we don't need your history, or to know that you're new here, etc. I'd suggest deleting the first slab and breaking down the second one into more readable chunks.

Answer (score 3):

Each `{` is a new scope. So for it to work make sure to define your variable before new scopes. e.g. before `if` , `switch`,  etc...

This also applies to classes. Defining variables after the name space put it in a class level scope.

```
public Student(string title, string name, string surname, string dob, string degreename = "") 
: base(title, name, surname, dob)
{
    //Method level scope
    var Studentslist = new List<string>();

    if (stucount == 0)
    {
        stucount++;
        Studentslist.Add(this.getStuIDtitleNameSurname()); 
    }
    else
    {
        stucount++;
        var studat = this.getStuIDtitleNameSurname();
        Studentslist.Add(studat);
    }
}
```

**HINT**:

- In modern programming you should always avoid doing counters. If you feel like this is the only solution you may have another problem.
- You should keep it simple and clean.
- You should use class level constructors to initialise variables. This is especially important with Dependency Injection.
- Also base classes are frowned upon. It violates the principles of **SOLID**. Always remember `Composition over inheritance` *(They use base in school/university to teach you about inheritance but you would only do that if you are building frameworks, for example .NET where allot of time and consideration is put into inheritance choices)*

A better version would be...

```
public int StudentCount => Students.Count;
public List<string> Students => {get; set;}

public Student() {
   Students = new List<string>();
}


public Student(string title, string name, string surname, string dob, string degreename = "") 
: base(title, name, surname, dob)
{
    Studentslist.Add(this.getStuIDtitleNameSurname()); 
}
```

It seems like you are learning programming so I would suggest reading a Design Patterns book.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a good/recommended Design Patterns book ?

Comment: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6oHuKQe3TjQC  The so called Gang Of Four Design patterns used in Universities. These are language agnostic and are a collection of patterns. You do not have to use all of them you just learn about the ones you need. If you search on stack overflow you will also get allot of help. It is really boring but once you get stuck on a problem.. you will remember what you read instantly and know how to proceed. But it also depends how long you have been programming. Simple OO tutorials are a good start too since you seem to be struggling with simple things